# Receiving messages by client without waiting for scanf()

Tags: c, client

I wonder how I can receive messages in client just after message is sent to it, instead of waiting for using `scanf()`. How I can change this loop to handle it? I can insert more code, if it's necessary. I want to have scanning function and reading fuction indepedendent

```
    while(1) {
        scanf("%[^\n]",hello);
        getchar();
        send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
        bzero(hello, sizeof(hello));
        valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);

        if(strcmp(buffer,"Server error, is closing") == 0) {
            exit(0);
        }

        printf("Received (yours name) (message): %s\n",buffer );
        bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
   }
```

EDIT -
This is the assignment, in which I can't use neither threads nor forks

Comment: Use separate threads to monitor the two sources of input?  Use poll/select to see which file descriptors have data ready?

Comment: I just read about `select`, can they be appropriate? I can't use neither threads nor forks, I should've added it to the question

Comment: On second read, I don't know what you're asking.  What is 'scan' in this context?  Is that a typo of 'send'?  If so, then `select` is my go-to for this issue in a single thread.

Comment: Post the definition of `hello, buffer`.

Comment: `Hello` and `buffer` are char arrays, declared by `malloc`. `Sock` is obviously a server

Comment: Please post a [mcve],   The current code forces each I/O transaction to be serially applied.  Suggest using `select()`  to watch both I/O sources at the same time.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%[^\n]",hello);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using '%s' or '%[...]', always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer (hello) so the buffer cannot be overflowed.  (remember those two input specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input)  Any buffer overflow results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when calling the functions: `send()` and `read()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful And for `read()`, always use the returned value (if >0) to terminate the input, so it can be printed or have any of the string functions used upon it.